# модификаторы БЭМ

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, бэм

Есть

```
<div class="Card">
   <div class="Status">
      содержимое
   </div>
</div>
```

Класс `Status` в стилях `display: none`.
Как через модификатор класса для `Card` сделать `Status` `display: block`?

Answer (score 2):

Вы, как мне кажется, тут вообще не применяете или не понимаете БЭМ:

- ему не нужна вложенность,
- элементы должны быть вместе с блоками в именах,
- модификаторы надо применить также с блоком или элементом в одном классе.

Допустим ситуация такая (если я верно понял вас): есть карточка и для неё есть статус, затем в некоторых случаях надо карты показывать или нет. Значит

- `card` будет блоком,
- `status` будет его элементом,
- `visible` будет модификатором (или придумайте более подходящее имя).

Тогда вёрстка будет такой:

```css
.card__status {
  display: none;
}

.card__status--visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="card__status">
      Это не будет видно.
   </div>

   <!-- используем модификатор --visible -->
   <div class="card__status card__status--visible">
      А вот это будет!
   </div>   
</div>
```